# Maven web app not deploying in local Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I've had a web app project on Eclipse Luna (created as Dynamic Web Project) for a while; in order to test, I used to use the option "Run on server", and it ran correctly on my Tomcat 7 server.

But now, I have mavenized the project, and there's no way I can run it as easily as I used to. Actually there's not even an option to "Run on server", just "Run as Java Application/Applet" if I click on the project folder or "Run as Maven install/build..." if I click on the pom.xml file.

Is there any way I can go back ti running my beloved webapp on my local server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your `pom.xlm`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>${tomcat.server.name}</server>
                <webapps>
                    <webapp>
                        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                        <path>/path</path>
                    </webapp>
                </webapps>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After this, you'll have to set some things in the Tomcat config. I set the following things in `tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users>
...
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

And set the `${tomcat.server.name}` variable's value in the Maven's `settings.xml` file (`~/.m2/settings.xml`), and some other stuff:

```
<settings>
...
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
       <tomcat.server.name>TomcatServer</tomcat.server.name>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
<servers>
<server>
<id>TomcatServer</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>admin</password>
</server>
</servers>
</settings>
```

After this, you'll be able to run, `mvn clean install tomcat:deploy` or `mvn clean install tomcat:redeploy`, and that'll run.

For more config info, see the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html)!